# Create OneNote notebook in document library (other than OneDrive) using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, onenote, onenote-api

I have created another document library in my personal sharepoint site. When I run the

```
GET /me/drives/
```

It shows both OneDrive and my created document library. Since I can create OneNote Notebook in the another document library from the UI, I want to achieve the same thing using graph api. However, currently supported graph api to create notebook are

```
POST /me/onenote/notebooks
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/onenote/notebooks
POST /groups/{id}/onenote/notebooks
POST /sites/{id}/onenote/notebooks
```

When I execute any one of these api, it always creates Notebook in the OneDrive. Is there any way to create Notebook in the specific document library?

Comment: MS graph API doesn't support creation of notebooks in a specific document library, based on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-post-notebooks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Onenote-API

```
POST https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/myOrganization/siteCollections/{id}/sites/{id}/notes/notebooks
```

or Graph-API

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/westerneye.sharepoint.com,{sitecollectionid},{siteid}/onenote/notebooks
```